# Есть какое ни будь свойство в wordress чтобы динамически подтягивать alt у картинки?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, gulp, cms

Картинка находиться в панели администратора в разделе записи. Не могу поменять alt у картинки. Есть какое ни буlь свойство в wordpress которое подставляла динамически этот alt?

Comment: Вы загружаете изображение через админ панель Wordpress? Распишите подробнее суть вашей проблемы и шаги действий, тогда будет проще вам дать болие правильный ответ

Answer (score 0):

Можешь [попробовать так](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)

```
<?php
$alt = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); 
<img src="<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" />
?>
```

Не понятно, как ты в админке это изображение выводишь. Надо код смотреть